# Get current http context user in .Net Core 2.0 WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, httpcontext

I have a .Net Core 2 WebAPI controller and need to retrieve the current user Id in either it's constructor or one of the routes.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ConfigController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ConfigController(IConfiguration iConfig)
    {
        _configuration = iConfig;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public AppSettings GetAppSettings()
    {
        var appSettings = new AppSettings
        {
            //Other settings
            CurrentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
        };
        return appSettings;
    }
}
```

The above `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` won't give me what I need. I figured I will need an equivalent of the .Net framework's `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Any idea?
Please note this is a .Net Core 2.0 WebAPI, please don't suggest solutions for the regular .net controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ControllerBase.User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-2.1) will hold the principle of the currently authenticated user for the request and will only be available in the scope of the executing action, not in the constructor.

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public AppSettings GetAppSettings() {
    var user = this.User;
    var appSettings = new AppSettings {
        //Other settings
        CurrentUser = user.Identity.Name
    };
    return appSettings;
}
```